# how to pass html option id or name or value from one view to another view's controller in MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm displaying dropdown list using html. then when a user select a item from the list that item's id or name or something should pass to my next view's controller.
this is my code...

***** this is my first controller  *****

```
public ActionResult searchView()
    {
        XElement cruProductRoot = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/Cruisedata/cruiseprodutstwo.xml"));
        var rootElement = cruProductRoot.Elements("CruiseProduct");//this is the root element
        //for the location field
        var getLocations =  rootElement
                           .Select(l => l.Element("Location").Value)
                           .Distinct();

        var getType = rootElement
                      .Select(t => t.Element("Types").Element("Type").Value)
                      .Distinct();
       // Test productsTestone = new Test();
        List<Test> productsLocation = new List<Test>();
        List<Test> productsType = new List<Test>();
        foreach (var iteml in getLocations)
        {
            productsLocation.Add(new Test
            {
                cruiseLocation = iteml.ToString()

            });
        };

        foreach(var itemt in getType)
        {
            productsType.Add(new Test 
            {
                cruiseType = itemt.ToString(),

            });
        }

        ViewBag.Lc = productsLocation;
        ViewBag.Tp = productsType;
        return View();
    }
```

*** and this is the view for the controller ****

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Test", "searchView", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group" style="background-color:#808080; padding:30px;">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin:10px;">
            <label for="location">Destination </label>
            <select id="location">
                <option>Any</option>
                @foreach (Test item in @ViewBag.Lc)
                {
                    <option value=@item.cruiseLocation>@item.cruiseLocation</option>
                }
                </select>
              </div>
</div>
```

******** this is my second controller ******

```
public ActionResult resultView(string value)
        {

            XElement sCruise = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/Cruisedata/cruiseprodutstwo.xml"));
            var rootEle = sCruise.Elements("CruiseProduct")
                          .Where(s => s.Element("Location").Value == value);

            foreach(var it in rootEle)
            {

            }

            return View();
        }
```

**** when user select an item from the list, and click submit then the selected item should send to the second view's controller. how can I do that. 
if we use only links like this.

```
@Html.ActionLink(@itme.cruiseLocation,"resultView", new {name =@item.cruiseLocatin})
```

how to do for option also.I tried `<option>@Html.ActionLink</option>` also. help me with this

Comment: You can use TempData to pass option id between to controller.

Comment: how to do that, I'm new to MVC

Answer (score 1):

In first controller set

```
TempData["optionid"]=selectedid
```

And in second controller you can access that id from  `var a=TempData["optionid"]`

Comment: I didn't understand, where to put this